# How to grab just the file from a filepath

Tags: c#, regex, filepath

Currently I have this path,

```
C:\Users\U6BRISON\Documents\DICOM Files\Trying.dcm
```

What I want to do is to just grab the last part: `Trying.dcm`

And edit it to a new file: `[Clean]Trying.dcm`

I believe I can use regex to do this but I'm not not sure if this is the best path forward. I want this to also be future proof so that I can identify any .dcm file and add the [Clean] tag to the front of the file.

Answer (score 2):

Will this not suffice? [System.IO.Path.GetFileName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getfilename?view=netframework-4.8) method.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
Path.GetFileName( filePath );
```

It will pull the file name (with extension) from the path for you.